# i have a problem with my lasso tool

Tags: modeling

i was watching a tutorial and making my first project (i'm new), and I've encountered this problem, my lasso tool keeps getting messed up and i don't know how to fix it, it is supposed that when i select something the tool looks like a square

[image]
but it looks like this when i try to use it

[image]
.

please help me as i am new to blender and its really bugging me how its changing every time
, i am not sure if i have pressed any button which is a shortcut to change a setting or something like that.

thank you.

Comment: The shortcut to cycle between the selection types is `W`. Maybe you pressed it by error ? In previous Blender versions this was mapped to a menu and older tutorials use it.

Comment: i might have been, thanks anyways mate, much apretiated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selection tool can be changed by

1. locating the tool bar in the top-left of the 3D Viewport (<kbd>T</kbd> if it is hidden)
2. long pressing on the selection tool icon (usually the arrow with the selection tool)
3. choosing the proper selection tool from the appearing menu

[image: menu]

Comment: thank you leander for your help, it worked.